# Clarification about flags on wrong questions

Tags: discussion, flags, too-localized

I've recently flagged a couple of questions:

- [setting http_headers in app.yaml doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989101/setting-http-headers-in-app-yaml-doesnt-work) (Flag message: OP has solved his mistake)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248030/c-sharp-httpwebresponse-error-502-bad-gateway (Flag message: OP has solved, he set the wrong Url)

and both flags were declined for the same reason:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that
>   requires their intervention

I flagged these questions because I thought they were in some way useless for the community and in particular for the [google-app-engine](/questions/tagged/google-app-engine) followers.
Why?
Because the problems that have originated both the questions were caused by some gross oversight.

In the first question, OP has posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989101/setting-http-headers-in-app-yaml-doesnt-work#comment16010963_11989101) comment clarification :

> *I found the problem. I changed the version and therefore the online version was not the deployed one. Restoring the version number made
>   the deployed version available online, and therefore the headers were
>   added.*

On second question, OP has posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8264088/130929) answer:

> *I found out what the problem was, I was sending the information to the wrong URL.*

In both the case, the fault made by the OP has invalidated the correctness of the question.

What's the correct behavior here?
Cast a close vote or flag for deletion?
In both questions I've also cast a close vote as "Too localized".

I've "succesfully" flagged other questions like these in the past leaving a message like (OP has solved by himself ..) and each time they were closed ore deleted by a moderator.

Comment: If I were to give that a quick glance (and I assume moderators have a crapload of these to go through) then I might as well think "Well, if he solved it, he should make it an answer. What's the point of this flag?". You're not wrong about it, but you can be more clear I think.

Comment: Voted to close on both as 'Too Localized'.

Comment: Another example: [Saving micro sign character in a mongo collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014362/12014579#comment16029927_12014579) (OP thought he had tested with decoding from Latin-1 but as it turns out he had not).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whenever I encounter a question where the OP's "solution" invalidates the premise of the question, I do two things:

1. I vote to close the question as "too localized". The question is pointless after all. No future answer will be of value since the whole premise of the question was flawed.
2. I flag for moderator attention. I usually leave a custom message telling about the "too localized" nature, linking to the particular comment made by the OP. The more clear you can be, the better. Try to take the guesswork out of it for a moderator. Don't make them search to find what you have already discovered.

In my personal flagging experience (which is reasonably successful) using these two steps usually ensures that the (IMO) appropriate action is taken.

It might perhaps sound somewhat like overkill to do the two, but I find it nicer to have at least multiple people appear in a closure reason rather than to put the full "blame" on the moderator.

Comment: _Don't make them search to find what you have already discovered_.. ah, now I see the problem in my flags.